# finding acceleration from a position function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I really need help finding an acceleration for a body moving on a coordinate line, of position $s = 9 + 11 \cos(t)$ , $f(t) = s$. It must be observed at time $t = \frac{\pi}3$ seconds. I've tried plugging time into the derivative, $s' = -11 \sin(t)$, but I am nearly positive that the answer couldn't be more wrong.

Comment: What is the $f(x)=s$ about? What is $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Acceleration should corresponds to the second derivative.

$$s" = - 11 \cos(t)$$

substitute $t = \frac{\pi}{3}$ to find your answer.

Remark: The first derivative corresponds to the velocity.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking for acceleration do you take the second derivative such that $s’’(t)=-11\cos (t)$ evaluated at $t=\frac{\pi}{3}$?

Comment: Sorry @SiongThyeGoh I was in the process of answering while you beat me to it.

Comment: it happens to everyone on this site. =)

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration is the second derivative of the position, so you need to take one more derivative before plugging in the time.